# Application settings in relational database

Tags: architecture, sql, architectural-patterns

There is an application of ours which has some experimental features. We want to enable it when user wants to enable. So they will change it in the UI and we are saving those to DB.

So we added those settings in database as key value pairs. DB table is designed as follows.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
Key             |            Value
-----------------------------------------------------------
X               |         Y:Z:W
```

In the column value, we may have multiple values for a single key. Such as different business units(Y,Z,W).

Is this a good design to have for an application?

We are not using file based settings as we don't have the permissions to server and changing multiple times is a pain with file based.

Comment: There isn't anything inherently wrong with this design. The problems you may face is query effeciency if you want to do something like "SELECT all where Value contains Z". As long as all you need is to fetch rows and then look at their `Value`s, I don't see any issues here

Comment: @Eldamir you might want to add this as an answer. The situation is not uncommon, and application settings in database is a reasonable approach.

Comment: I could, but I feel like a full answer should dig a bit deeper than what I offered here. So for now, I'll leave it as a comment :)

Comment: I read recently in DB normalisation that, one column must have one value. This design then violates normalisation. Did I understand that correct?

Comment: How do you deploy if you don't have permission to write files?    It's common for CI/deployment tools to control app configuration (e.g. through configuration files, environment variables, etc.) because they already have all the permissions and information about each target environment

Comment: @T.kowshikYedida: Yes, you understood this correctly.  However, in this case, all of the values will be retrieved as a /single unit/ so, as far as the Database is concerned, they /are/ a single value.  It is the Application that then decomposes the [single] value retrieved into the many configuration properties that it needs.  Also, none of the individual /parts/ of the stored value are ever used to /query/ that field, which is the main reason why Normalisation stipulates "one column, one value".

Comment: @BenCottrell there is a separate team which handles deployments. We have to schedule a slot to do any changes to production.

Comment: @PhillW that means, if we are querying for values inside the column, then only this design violates normalisation?

Comment: @BenCottrell when we do with file based, we have to handle the modes and concurrency. Whereas in DB, it is easy to handle in our opinion. So, we went ahead with DB approach.

Comment: It sounds like your team doesn't really own the production environment, so  a bit concerning that your team are being required to take responsibility for something that the organisation policy has effectively designated to another team.   It sounds like the policy itself needs to be challenged and either loosened or for responsibility to toggle features re-assigned to whoever owns the production environment, otherwise you're essentially building a back-door to circumvent a policy control.

Comment: @T.kowshikYedida In the strictest terms, it violates the principle but, in practical terms, it doesn't matter.  Pragmatism can be a powerful tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I read recently in DB normalisation that, one column must have one value. This design then violates normalisation. Did I understand that correct?

To the letter of the law, yes. Normalisation dictates that your table structure should be:

| Key | Department | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | A | value1 |
| X | B | value2 |
| X | C | value3 |

**BUT** this assumes that the data structure applies to all your config values, i.e. all of them are department-based. If this is the case, then this is the right structure.

However, config tables are often a mishmash of different config values with different structures. Trying to generate a table structure that fits all of them, or designing individual tables for all kinds of config values; is often not worth the effort.

In this case, it is acceptable to step away from the letter of the law of data normalization, and instead resort to a more broad-sweeping compatible data structure. Your proposal is one valid way of approaching this. It may suffice for your use case, and then there's no reason to make things more complex on yourself.

Personally, I tend to work with a strongly typed language (C#), and therefore I have a habit of storing my custom-structure objects using serialization, which requires two columns: one for the serialized data, and one for the data type (needed for deserialization).

Something along the lines of:

| Key | Type | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ConfigValue1 | MyApp.Config.Credentials | { "id": "12345", "secret": "abcde" } |
| ConfigValue2 | MyApp.Config.DepartmentConfigValue | { "X": "value2_for_department_X", "Y": "value2_for_department_Y", "Z": "value2_for_department_Z" } |
| ConfigValue3 | MyApp.Config.DepartmentConfigValue | { "X": "value3_for_department_X", "Y": "value3_for_department_Y", "Z": "value3_for_department_Z" } |

This allows me to store data of any format (if it is serializable, which isn't an issue for config values) without ever needing to update my table structure, which is nice for compatibility reasons as a config table is often an essential component. It also allows me to easily load this data in a way that a strongly typed language (I'm a C# dev) can automatically convert it back to the strongly-typed config object that I prefer working with in code.

*Note: I've dabbled with letting Newtonsoft.Json set the concrete type into the JSON data itself. This works well, and I really like that feature when serializing to a file. But for this kind of config table, I prefer to omit it when possible, simply to keep the JSON string easier to manually adjust. In a file, indentation can avoid the issue and there's no problem with baking the concrete type into the data, but database management tools tend not to have great multiline text support.*

This is just one example of how you can approach a loose data structure in your database while keeping it more strongly typed in your codebase.

Comment: Good approach. I never thought about the binding way. As you mentioned about other approaches are also possible, do you have any other approaches which you can update in your answer.

Comment: @T.kowshikYedida: Essentially any arbitrary serialization to a string format would work. Base64 encoding, comma-separation for tabular data, ... the world truly is your oyster here. Once you use such a vague "data" column that can contain any string, this is no different from how you'd decide how to store your data in a file.